# Overload Struct Operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Trying to figure out the solution to implement comparison operators in C++.  I have a struct for which I want whenever it is being compared with another struct of its type. I took out a bunch of code just to keep everything minimal

```
struct HuffNode{

    //Comparison stuff.. needed in Pqueue
    bool operator> (const HuffNode&) const;
    bool operator>=(const HuffNode&) const;
    bool operator==(const HuffNode&) const;
    bool operator<=(const HuffNode&) const;
    bool operator< (const HuffNode&) const;

};
```

Here is my test code for how I go about seeing if this works. Define just two node structures, and then try comparing them. Right now I thought I defined it so == will always return true, so the statement "HEYYYYYY111" should always print..

```
 HuffNode *hn1 = new HuffNode(0,0,0,0);
    HuffNode *hn2 = new HuffNode(0,0,0,0);
    if( hn1 == hn2 ){
        cout << "HEYYYYYY111" << endl;
    }
```

Right now I have the constant simply defined just like this. Just for the sake of testing this will always returns true, and that If loop above should print out. However it does not

```
  bool HuffNode::operator==(const HuffNode  &f) const {
        return true;
    }
```

Anyone have any idea as to how to address this? Not entirely sure.. the only thing I could think of is not having the correct arguments. My goal is to use this in a template class so I can compare the two structs.

Comment: You're comparing pointers. Compare objects instead.

Comment: You're comparing the pointers, which are unlikely to be the same.

Comment: You also need to really implement one operator, clasically `operator<`. All other operators can be implemented in terms of this operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
if( *hn1 == *hn2 ){
    cout << "HEYYYYYY111" << endl;
}
```

with "*" you access the value (in this case object), and it should call your overloaded operator.